# html/css Main wrapping Div stays at the same dimensions when page is zoomed out (ctr-)

Tags: html, css

Thats the problem. When I zoom out the page using ctrl minus this bug comes alive. My wrapping div and the 3 columns I have within it do not size down with the page when I zoom out but rather stay the same whilst everything else (images,text) shrink down.

I have uploaded the problem to http://www.amasi.co.tz | Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: can you add some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use percent instead of fixed width

```
.wrap{
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80%;
}
```

Comment: No change, i uploaded the sample code to http://www.amasi.co.tz if you can have a look and try to zoom out on your browser.